# Concourse CI will not run Hello-World after setting up with the official docker image. It fails showing "no workers"

Tags: docker, continuous-integration, concourse

I recently set up concourse CI using the following docker-compose: https://concourse-ci.org/docker-repository.html and then tried the flight school training here: https://concourse-ci.org/flight-school.html and then, when that failed showing "no workers", I attempted the hello-world here: https://concourse-ci.org/hello-world.html.

I keep seeing an error saying "no workers". If I had to guess, this is because of a simple configuration issue on my end, but I am having trouble tracking it down.

Can someone please help me figure out how to debug this, I do not see errors in the docker startup logs. Searching for the problem is showing seemingly unrelated errors.

Answer (score 0):

I talked with the team and it appears it was a race condition in v3.1 that I was running. Updating to v3.2 fixed the issues and everything is running smoothly.